# Pasting multiple files only shows one file

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to paste multiple files in the following input field, but `from_clipboard` only logs one file. How do I get all three files?

```
<input type="text" class="input-clipboard" @paste="from_clipboard">

from_clipboard(event){
  console.log('hello clipboard')
  var files = event.clipboardData.files;
  console.log(files)
},
```

Comment: `<input multiple="multiple" />`